# How to create dynamically a BKS keystore + certificate in Android

Tags: certificate, bouncycastle, keystore

i have a problem with creating dynamically (without using keytool) a BKS keystore+certificate in android.

I already have created a BKS keystore with BouncyCastle in my desktop app: 
SEE:

```
public class KeyStoreGenerator {

public static void main(String[] args){
    generateKeyStore("1234567", "Burcu Cinarci", "TU Dortmund", "Informatik", "Dortmund", "NRW", "DE");
}
public static void generateKeyStore(String password, String cn, String o, String ou, String l, String st, String c) {
    try {
        Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider()); 
        final java.security.KeyPairGenerator rsaKeyPairGenerator = java.security.KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
        rsaKeyPairGenerator.initialize(2048);
        final KeyPair rsaKeyPair = 
rsaKeyPairGenerator.generateKeyPair();

        // Generate the key store de type JCEKS
        Provider[] ps = Security.getProviders();
        for (int i = 0; i < ps.length; i++)
            System.out.println("" + ps[i].getName());

        final KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("BKS");
        ks.load(null);

        final RSAPublicKey rsaPublicKey = (RSAPublicKey) rsaKeyPair.getPublic();

        System.out.println("LOG: format "+rsaPublicKey.getFormat());
        char[] pw = password.toCharArray();

        final RSAPrivateKey rsaPrivateKey = (RSAPrivateKey) rsaKeyPair.getPrivate();
        final java.security.cert.X509Certificate certificate = makeCertificate(rsaPrivateKey, rsaPublicKey, cn, o, ou, l, st, c);
        final java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] certificateChain = { certificate };

certificateChain);
        ks.setKeyEntry("operator", rsaKeyPair.getPrivate(), pw, certificateChain);

        File keyStoreFile= new File("keyStore.ks");
        final FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(
                keyStoreFile);
        ks.store(fos, pw);
        fos.close();
        System.out.println(keyStoreFile.getAbsolutePath());

        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore",
                keyStoreFile.getAbsolutePath());
        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword", "1234567");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static X509Certificate makeCertificate(PrivateKey issuerPrivateKey,
        PublicKey subjectPublicKey, String cn, String o, String ou, String l, String st, String c) throws Exception {

    final org.bouncycastle.asn1.x509.X509Name issuerDN = new org.bouncycastle.asn1.x509.X509Name(
            "CN="+cn+", OU="+ou+", O="+o+", L="+l+", ST="+st+", C="+c);

    final org.bouncycastle.asn1.x509.X509Name subjectDN = new org.bouncycastle.asn1.x509.X509Name(
            "CN="+cn+", OU="+ou+", O="+o+", L="+l+", ST="+st+", C="+c);
    final int daysTillExpiry = 10 * 365;

    final Calendar expiry = Calendar.getInstance();
    expiry.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, daysTillExpiry);

    final org.bouncycastle.x509.X509V3CertificateGenerator certificateGenerator = new org.bouncycastle.x509.X509V3CertificateGenerator();

    certificateGenerator.setSerialNumber(java.math.BigInteger
            .valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()));
    certificateGenerator.setIssuerDN(issuerDN);

    certificateGenerator.setSubjectDN(subjectDN);
    certificateGenerator.setPublicKey(subjectPublicKey);
    certificateGenerator.setNotBefore(new Date());
    certificateGenerator.setNotAfter(expiry.getTime());

    certificateGenerator.setSignatureAlgorithm("MD5WithRSA");

    return certificateGenerator.generate(issuerPrivateKey);
}

}
```

But in my android sdk, i can`t add the bouncycastle-jar file, because it is already included in android. (bouncycastle as provider exists already)

But why can't I find the "org.bouncycastle..." package?

The following code in the methode makeCertificate, which generates the certificate dynamically, does not work because eclipse cant find the specific package:

```
final org.bouncycastle.asn1.x509.X509Name subjectDN = new    org.bouncycastle.asn1.x509.X509Name("CN="+cn+", OU="+ou+", O="+o+", L="+l+", 
ST="+st+", C="+c);
```

I have tried to add additionally the bouncycastle.jar file, but it doesn`t work, because of redundance of bouncycastle.

---

thank you for your post.. the problem is still, that android don`t know the classes
X509V3CertificateGenerator and 
X509Principal.

Android don't know any classes of bouncycastle. I can change the class X509Principal to X500Principal, which exists in the package javax.security.auth.x500 but i can't replace any class for the CertificateGenerator

thx

Comment: org.bouncycastle.asn1.x509.X509Name is in the bcprov-jdk.jar

Comment: i know, that the classes are in the jar file, but i cant add the jar-file to my android sdk, because it exists already as a provider in the android sdk :S

Answer (score 1):

The bouncycastle included in Android is "crippled". If you want to work with the full bouncycastle library like in a desktop app, take a look at [the spongycastle library](https://rtyley.github.io/spongycastle/).

It it essentially the same as Bouncycastle, except all package names have been moved from org.bouncycastle.* to org.spongycastle.*.

So, in your code, include the spongycastle library and replace every org.bouncycastle.* with org.spongycastle.* and it should work like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you get that exception and the post is hard to read due to the bad format, but if your problem is the line:

`final org.bouncycastle.asn1.x509.X509Name issuerDN = new org.bouncycastle.asn1.x509.X509Name(
            "CN="+cn+", OU="+ou+", O="+o+", L="+l+", ST="+st+", C="+c);`

You don't need that.

Do the following:

```
String dn =  "CN="+cn+", OU="+ou+", O="+o+", L="+l+", ST="+st+", C="+c;
X509V3CertificateGenerator certificateGenerator = new X509V3CertificateGenerator();
certificateGenerator.setSubjectDN(new X509Principal(dn));
```

This should be working for you ok.

Comment: thank you for your post.. the problem is still, that android don`t know the classes X509V3CertificateGenerator and X509Principal.

Android don't know any classes of bouncycastle. I can change the class X509Principal to X500Principal, which exists in the package javax.security.auth.x500 but i can't replace any class for the CertificateGenerator

thx

Comment: But I am not suggesting to change the `certificateGenerator`.The only code different is that you do `setSubjectDN` in the certificate generator